# Grails generate-views runs twice

Tags: grails, code-generation

Running 'grails generate-views' or '... generate-all' commands cause generation process running twice in one cycle:

```
| Generating views for domain class recreation.Region  
> File \grails-app\views\region\create.gsp already exists. Overwrite?[y,n,a] y  
> File \grails-app\views\region\edit.gsp already exists. Overwrite?[y,n,a] y  
> File \grails-app\views\region\list.gsp already exists. Overwrite?[y,n,a] y  
> File \grails-app\views\region\show.gsp already exists. Overwrite?[y,n,a] y  
> File \grails-app\views\region\_form.gsp already exists. Overwrite?[y,n,a] y  
> File \grails-app\views\region\create.gsp already exists. Overwrite?[y,n,a] y  
> File \grails-app\views\region\edit.gsp already exists. Overwrite?[y,n,a] y  
> File \grails-app\views\region\list.gsp already exists. Overwrite?[y,n,a] y  
> File \grails-app\views\region\show.gsp already exists. Overwrite?[y,n,a] y  
> File \grails-app\views\region\_form.gsp already exists. Overwrite?[y,n,a] y  
| Generating controller for domain class recreation.Region
```

Some hidden meaning exists here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run the "install-templates" script for the project?

It appears that the generate scripts look in several places and runs for each template it finds.  It seems like it starts in $GRAILS_HOME/src/grails/templates/scaffolding and generates based on those, then goes to the custom templates in your project and generates based on those, so it is overwriting at that point.

Comment: Seems to be true.. Nevertheless behaviour can't say to be smart.